# Subpixel and letter-spacing

Tags: html, css

I would like to use `letter-spacing` on my headings. The headings are responsive: at smaller screen sizes, the headings have a smaller `font-size`. Therefore it makes sense to use `em` for the letter-spacing measurement.

I've noticed that this results in subpixle `letter-spacing`. It appears fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on my Mac, but will it work across all browsers? Or will some (older) browsers round to the nearest pixel?

I want to avoid browsers rounding down to zero - therefore ignoring the letter-spacing. Or rounding up to 1 and the letter-spacing being too loose.

I read this post from several years ago, which implies browsers rounded subpixles [Web-Kit and sub-pixel values, workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655697/web-kit-and-sub-pixel-values-workaround/12695468#12695468)

```
h1 {
    font-size:7.2rem; /* equals 72px */
    letter-spacing:0.01em; /* equals 0.72px */
    }
```

Comment: Use font-size in PX format

Comment: The computed size is in pixels: 72px. So the letter spacing of 0.01em = 0.72px letter spacing. My question is will all/most browers cope with sub-pixels? Or will they round them?

Comment: Could your questions be reworded to "Is there currently any browser that does not use subpixel text rendering?"? What exactly you want to ensure, achieve or prevent?

Comment: See edit to question

Comment: @myf is there currently any browser that does not support subpixel letter-spacing??

Answer (score 2):

Following more research it appears that modern browsers do support sub-pixel letter-spacing see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/